# i cant add pagination to front-end.php in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

i have my wordpress setting as homepage static page (front-page.php) and my posts page is a separate page (index.php), i pulled the posts into index.php and added the pagination with no problem. anyways i want to have a section in my homepage that also has the posts pulled in with pagination. i was able to pull in the posts through wordpress loop but i couldn't add the pagination, i tried several methods to add pagination but i couldn't when i click a next page it changes the page number in the url and the site reloads but the posts dont change.
here is the code for front-page.php :

```
    <?php
    get_header()
    ?>
    <?php
    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'home');
    ?>

    <div class="container-worksheets" style="padding-top: 0;">
        <div class="cards-container" style="padding-top: 0;">
            <?php
            //define the query arguments
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post', //get only posts
                'posts_per_page' => 4, //get 10 posts per page
                'orderby' => 'date', //order by date
                'order' => 'DESC', //order from newest to oldest
            );

            //create a new WP_Query object with the arguments
            $query = new WP_Query($args);

            //check if the query has any posts
            if ($query->have_posts()) {

                //loop through the posts
                while ($query->have_posts()) {

                    //set up the post data
                    $query->the_post();

                    //use your template part to display the post
            ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="card-items">
                            <div class="img-holder">
                                <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="featured image">
                            </div>
                            <div class="info">
                                <p><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></p>
                                <div class="hide">
                                    <p> <?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0, 100); ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <span><?php echo get_the_category()[0]->name; ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <span>workshhets</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
            <?php

                }

                //reset the post data
                wp_reset_postdata();
            } else {

                //if no posts are found, display a message
                echo '<p>No posts found.</p>';
            }
            ?>
            <?php the_posts_pagination(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    


    <?php
    get_footer()
    ?>
```

here is the index.php where everything works (btw i also tried to copy the same code to home page but it didn't work)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-worksheets">
    <div class="cards-container">
        <?php
            if (have_posts()){

                while(have_posts()){
                    the_post();
                    get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'archive');
                }
                

            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
    the_posts_pagination();
?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

i tried several wordpress methods but none worked

Comment: Can you please add the URL for the second page to your question?

Comment: what do you mean by second page ? and im running locally now btw

Comment: "when i click a next page it changes the page number in the url"

Comment: like this : http://localhost/wordpress/page/2/

Comment: thats the url when i click next, the page refreshes and the posts do not change

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `WP_Query` instance isn't implementing [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters). Try this for your `$args`:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'paged'          => absint( get_query_var( 'page', 1 ) ),
);
```

Comment: that did not work

Comment: Updated answer: changed `paged` to `page`.